# Replace text with predefined value in browser

Tags: mac

I used to have a tool on my PC that would allow me to prefill text when I enter certain "codes". For example, I would type $test123 and it would replace that text with a sentence that I had setup.

Is there a similar program on the Mac that also works in any browser?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html).

From their site:

> Type more with less effort! TextExpander saves your fingers and your keyboard, expanding custom keyboard shortcuts into frequently-used text and pictures...

Comment: that's it. A bit pricey at $35 ...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting each *replacement* word with it's value under **System Preferences / Language & Text.**

[image]

If after trying it out, it doesn't work, you may need to enable the text substitution feature. To do so just go **Edit / Substitution / Text Replacement** or right click on a editable field for the *edition* menu to show up:

[image]

You could, though, enable the text substitution feature on every Application which supports it just by executing this command on **Terminal**:  `defaults write -g WebAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled -bool true`

Comment: thanks. That works in mac apps like textedit but not in the chrome browser using gmail.